How to add "Back to Cart" Button at checkout page in magento 2
I want to add "Back to Cart" Button at checkout page Near the "Next" button
docker.com/checkout/#shipping
Please help

To add a new button beside the "Next" button, override the below file in your theme/module.
vendor\magento\module-checkout\view\frontend\web\template\shipping.html

Add your link to the actions-toolbar div
<div class="actions-toolbar" id="shipping-method-buttons-container">
    <div class="primary">
        <button data-role="opc-continue" type="submit" class="button action continue primary">
            <span translate="'Next'"></span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="secondary">
        <a href="#" data-bind="attr: { href: getCartUrl() }" >Back to Cart</a>
    </div>
</div>

Create a mixin of shipping.js file and add a new function getCartUrl to return the cart page URL.

Hi  i am new to magento, can you please share the shipping.js file
